# Calculate Percentage in Label based of two textbox value without AutoPostBack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

its been a day trying to find out the solution. but unsuccessful.
I am just trying to create a percentage calculation table for my students.
Here is my .aspx code

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txt1").val("");
            $("#txt2").val("");
        });
        function txtHSpercentage() {
            ch1 = $("#txt1").val();
            ch2 = $("#txt2").val();
            ch3 = (ch1 / 100) * ch2;
            document.getElementById("#txthsP").value = (ch3.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #table1
        {
            border: solid thin black;
        }

            #table1 td
            {
                border: solid thin black;
                width: 30px;
                text-align: center;
            }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <table id="table1" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 50%; border: solid thin black; margin-top: 100px">
        <tr>
            <td>HS</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Width="90%" onkeyup="txtHSpercentage()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" Width="90%" onkeyup="txtHSpercentage()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="txthsP" runat="server" Width="90%" ForeColor="Black" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Its Not working at all. I just want to get the value when user enter value in txthsMO.
it should work like calculator.
is it possible or NOT.
Please Help.....

UPDATE :-
in ViewpageSource its showing like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txt1").val("");
            $("#txt2").val("");
        });
        function txtHSpercentage() {
            ch1 = $("#txt1").val();
            ch2 = $("#txt2").val();
            ch3 = (ch1 / 100) * ch2;
            document.getElementById("#txthsP").value = (ch3.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #table1
        {
            border: solid thin black;
        }

            #table1 td
            {
                border: solid thin black;
                width: 30px;
                text-align: center;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default3.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="cHuYm1VLP9az8bfSVVpFYL2zGIUY+7Jr6iWOLhPF2jhHns5K4u5zhkPWMkN6qiw6WsTTsDIUJxBVutesBKtzOj66kjVPVjPxzF+wz+3Mhv4=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="8sEsxlU6EE+aaqKCbHV0992JS44nu7cKDzulDBEkeZthEts5PY0j05tUanKAHJUYfsL+0tG8j9r4ULWq62a4zj93fDQwm/vzykw31K+1sP1ly4FihsKHIqZ16Y1cXWKlNgOgZ9xj22pI9+Dc7uRCyw==" />
</div>
    <div>
        
    <table id="table1" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 50%; border: solid thin black; margin-top: 100px">
        <tr>
            <td>HS</td>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt1" type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="txtHSpercentage()" style="width:90%;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt2" type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="txtHSpercentage()" style="width:90%;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="txthsP" style="display:inline-block;color:Black;width:90%;"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also added ClientIDMode="Static" at top of page
Please Help...

Comment: You are not far away from the solution. WebForms generates combined ids so you need to take a look at the generated HTML in the browser using "view source". It will be something along the line of xxx_Content:2_txt1. If you use these ids in your jquery code, you should be be able to read/write the values. For debugging purposes you can use alert( $("#idtotest").length) to make sure the selected element actually exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing: you should use `txt1` and `txt2` in your code instead of `Text1` and `Text2`.

Since the ID of each TextBox is probably combined with the name of a container (as mentioned in @schudel's comment), the following syntax is a safer way to get the correct ID:

```
var ch1 = $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val();
var ch2 = $("#<%= txt2.ClientID %>").val();
var ch3 = (ch1 / 100) * ch2;
$("#<%= txthsP.ClientID %>").text(ch3.toFixed(2));
```

An alternative would be to set the `ClientIDMode` of the TextBox to `Static`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ... />
```

which preserves the original ID. You can then use it to retrieve the control:

```
$("#txt1")
```

Comment: i add as u said. but its not working yet. please help

Comment: In code-behind, can you access `txt1`? For example, can you write: `string s = txt1.Text;`? If so, the "ClientID" syntax should work. If you put an alert in your `txtHSpercentage` function, like `alert($("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val());`, does it show the value found in that TextBox?

Comment: I updated my answer. I showed how to use jQuery to write the calculated value in `txthsP` (since you used jQuery in the rest of your code). If it still doesn't work, you can use `alert` to view `ch2` and `ch3`. Or use `console.log(ch2)` and see the output in the console window (displayed with F12 in most browsers).

Comment: I want it in label because after entering all d fields from it can be insert into database table.. Its working outside contentplaceholder.  Like in HTML page

Comment: I updated again. Sorry, I hadn't noticed that `txthsP` is a `span` element. By the way, when I mentioned `console.log`, it was as a debugging tool, like `alert`.

Comment: THANKS it works ("_") Question - is it work in all browser ???? Looking forward for future help ...

Comment: You're welcome! It should work in all browsers. jQuery is implemented for that, and the `<%= %>` expressions are processed by the server code, so they do not depend on the browser.

Comment: SOLVED using $('input:text[id$=txtgP]').val(ch3.toFixed(2)); is it OK !